# Why do we need to write "*" after classpath

Tags: java, xml, spring

Why do we need to write "*" after classpath
Here's an example

```
<import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/config.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a regex pattern (specially for spring) which  means match `rest of the location path`.

Here in your case  match  all `config.xml` files in `META-INF/spring` folders of your classpath.

Here the Spring reference which exaplains it better in better way

[4.7.2 Wildcards in application context constructor resource paths](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

The resource paths in application context constructor values may be a simple path (as shown above) which has a one-to-one mapping to a target Resource, or alternately may contain the **special "classpath*:" prefix and/or internal Ant-style regular expressions** (matched using Spring's PathMatcher utility). Both of the latter are effectively wildcards

Comment: If it's regex, that means it accepts zero or more `h` characters after `classpat`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's a regex type special prefix.

Comment: The prefix has nothing to do with either regular expressions or any other kind of pattern matching.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think, technically, this sort of wildcarding does count as a regular expression -- that is, it describes a (very simple) regular language. But you're right to point out that it's not what people think of as a regex 99% of the time.

Comment: But @yshavit note that the actual feature does no pattern matching at all. The path specification is taken _literally_ and the feature is about something completely different.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, but I was referring specifically to your first comment, "if it's regex...".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, the way spring given the syntax to select those specified files make feels/treat like regex (*though not actaully*), that's the reason why I wrote *specially for spring*.

Comment: @yshavit That was a bit tongue-in-cheek :) Suresh seems to be confusing the Ant-style pattern matching which is available anyway (a feature orthogonal to the `classpath*` prefix) with the special semantics of `classpath*`. The asterisk in the prefix has no link to pattern matching.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Coffee in 3...2...1... ;)

Answer (score 4):

The `classpath*:` prefix means that, instead of just retrieving the first entry from the specified classpath location, *all* such entries will be used and merged together. Since each component (JAR) can contribute its own resource on the same classpath location, this makes it possible for each component to contribute its definitions into a common resource.